# CSS 2.1 spec: 8.3.1 Collapsing margins: cannot properly interpret special case: clarification sought

Tags: css, margin, margins

[Section 8.3.1 of the CSS 2.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) on collapsing margins states:

> If the top and bottom margins of an element with clearance are
> adjoining, its margins collapse with the adjoining margins of
> following siblings but that resulting margin does not collapse with
> the bottom margin of the parent block.

Here is my, surely erratic, attempt at making something out of this statement:

The statement considers an element X for which:

- X has clearance, therefore either of the "clear: left;", "clear: right;"
  or "clear: both;" properties have been applied to it.
- Since the top AND bottom margins of X are adjoining,
  in the case of a normal flow we are considering the scenario where:

  - X has one parent above and one sibling below, or
  - X has one sibling above and one sibling below, or
  - X has one sibling above and one parent below
- Then the spec says, "its margins collapse with the adjoining margins
  of following siblings", but there can be at most one following sibling,
  as pointed out above, so this essentially must mean that if there is a
  sibling following then the margin collapses.
- "but that resulting margin does not collapse with the bottom margin
  of the parent block." - I don't understand this: if the bottom margin
  is adjacent to a sibling's top margin then it cannot be adjacent to
  the parent block's bottom margin unless the sibling's height is zero.

I'm utterly confused. Can someone please explain this statement in a better way, perhaps with a few illustrative examples?

Comment: There are countless resources on the web about collapsing margins. read a bunch and try some code. Ex: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the response. I've read that post and understood everything except for "cleared elements (They do not collapse their top margins with their parent block’s bottom margin.)". Here a picture would be useful. If an element's top margin collapses with the parent block's bottom margin, to me this means the height of the child is zero. Makes no sense whatsoever. Perhaps someone can explain it.

Comment: However this does not answer my question. How can I interpret this section of the spec?

Comment: It's a good question. Attempts at a fiddle that would demonstrate the rule actually doesn't demonstrate anything. Therefore I challenge everybody, especially the people trying to close this, to come up with a fiddle that actually has non-collapsed margins in this situation.

Comment: Indeed, this line of the spec is so puzzling that I'd even like to start a bounty on this question, but I don't see where the option to start the bounty is. How can I start a bounty on this question?

Comment: Oh... I was going to point you to the [Help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) that has a page about how bounties work, but the page doesn't mention some of the conditions, that you need a minimum of 75 rep to start one. I'll see if I can rectify that.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like we won't be having an answer to this question, none so far anyways.

Comment: I think that statement on Sitepoint is just a bad wording, and I have no clue what they mean since as you correctly state it cannot make sense unless the child is zero height. I've tested it and it [does collapse](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/JH6XH/) like you would expect, and which is logical behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, It would be nice if a documentation bug could be submitted to the appropriate W3C working group, perhaps posting a link to this thread. Any idea where the appropriate place for this would be?

Answer (score 5):

First, a couple of clarifications:

- An element with clearance is one which has `clear` set to something other than `none` **and** is actually clearing a float.
- An element whose top and bottom margin are *adjoining* means adjoining with each other, not with siblings. We're talking about a 0 height element without border or padding, so the top margin and bottom margin of the element are touching each other. When this happens, they collapse with together, a situation known as *collapsing through*.

Now, let's look at an example:

```css
body {
  border:solid;
}
#container {
 margin: 20px;
 background: blue;
}
#floated {
 float: left;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background: red;
}
#cleared {
 clear: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#following {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id=container>
  <div id=floated></div>
  <div id=cleared></div>
  <div id=following></div>
<div>
</body>
```

Play with it here: http://jsbin.com/wuvilu/1/edit?html,css,output

Since there is a border on the body, you can see the 20px margin around the blue #container. The red #floated is also an obvious 20px by 20px.

Then, since it is 0 height with no padding and no border, the top and bottom margin of the #cleared collapse with each other. They are also adjoining with the top margin of the #following. The size of this collapsed margin is 30px, the largest of the three.

Since the #following is 0 height and has no padding and no border, our 30px margin is adjoining with the bottom margin of the #container, and would collapse with it. Except now the rule you have quoted kicks in, and it doesn't.

Since it won't collapse with the bottom margin of the container, it has to be placed somewhere within it. Where? It starts from 10px above the bottom edge of #floater, and extends 20px below. Why? The top margin of #cleared is the top-most margin that participates in this collapse margin, so we start where it would start. Since it is 10px, our collapsed margin starts 10px above the bottom edge of #floater, the element immediately before it.

Yes, this is insane, and most scenarios that involve collapsing through are insane. Collapsing **through** was a terrible idea, and it should never have made it into CSS, but it did before people knew better, and now we have to deal with it, and all the crazy consequences.

Comment: I disagree collapsing as a whole was a terrible idea - it's literally the "paragraph spacing" mechanic of CSS, something that made perfect sense during its time. The only problem is that it really should have been restricted to separating runs of text. But CSS has no way of distinguishing between two block containers containing only IFCs and two block-level boxes of any other nature, and *that* IMO is the real reason for the insanity we have to deal with today. (I get that you can just do `p+p { margin-top: 1em }` or something, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: I did not say that collapsing as a whole was a terrible idea. Only that collapsing *through* was. Collapsing the bottom margin of a `<p>` with the top margin of the next `<p>` is a good idea. Collapsing the top margin of a `<p>` with the bottom margin *of the same* `<p>` when it is empty was a bad one.